# Configuring PHPUnit on Server in PHPStorm 3.0 using XML configuration file

Tags: testing, configuration, phpunit, phpstorm

I would like to run PHPUnit tests on the development server as opposed to my desktop.

Using PHPStorm Run debug configuration I have created new PHPUnit on Server configuration.

However when I try to run it, PHPStorm does not seem to be able to see the XML configuration file. The path to the XML configuration file is on the local desktop, so it makes sense that PHPStorm runner would not be able to find the file on the server. However PHPStorm does not allow me to supply the path on the server.

P.S. I was able to run tests manually on the server and on my local desktop. In this question I am trying to figure out how to run the tests on the server directly from PHPStorm.

P.P.S. Could this be a bug in PHPStorm? if yes, then I'll submit it.

Comment: Are you executing phpunit on your local desktop or on the remote(?) server?

Comment: Please submit a new issue http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/WI#newissue=yes. Thanks!

Comment: @hakre: On remote server. But According to Nikolay, it does seem to be a PHPStorm issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far this seems to be an issue in PHPStorm. I have filed the issue here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issue/WI-9369